# Graph representation using Map and Set

Tags: c++, stl

```
    using namespace std;
    static int index = 0;
    template<typename T>
    class vertexInfo
    {
        public:

                 typename  map< T, int>:: iterator vtxMapLoc;              
                 vertexInfo<T>(int index)
                 {}
                 vertexInfo<T>( typename  map<T, int> :: iterator& iter) : vtxMapLoc{*iter}
                 {}

    };
    template <typename T>
    class graph
    {
        private:

                typename  map< T, int > :: iterator iter;
                map <T,int> vtxMap;
                vector<vertexInfo<T> > vInfo;  
        public:
                void addEdge( graph<T>& , const T& , const T&, int );
                void show(graph<T>& );
                void show_map_element( graph<T>& );



    };
    int main()
    {
        graph<char> g;
        g.addEdge(g,'A','B', 2);
        g.addEdge(g,'A','C', 3);
        g.addEdge(g,'B','D', 5);
        g.addEdge(g,'C','D', 1);
        g.addEdge(g,'B','C', 7);
        g.addEdge(g,'D','E', 4);
        g.show(g);
        g.show_map_element(g);
        return 0;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void graph<T> :: addEdge ( graph<T> & g, const T& v1 , const T& v2, int w)
    {
        pair <map <char, int> :: iterator, bool> ret ;

         ret = g.vtxMap.insert(pair <char, int >( v1, index));

         if( ret.second)
         {

            g.vInfo.push_back(index);
            (g.vInfo[index].vtxMapLoc) = vtxMap.find(index);   
            index++;

          }

         ret = g.vtxMap.insert(pair <char, int >(v2 , index));

         if( ret.second)
         {

            g.vInfo.push_back(index);
            (g.vInfo[index].vtxMapLoc) = vtxMap.find(index);    
            index++;
          }

       }
 }
template<typename T>
void graph<T> :: show( graph<T>& g)
{
    for( g.iter = g.vtxMap.begin(); g.iter != g.vtxMap.end(); g.iter++)
         {
             cout<< (*(g.iter)).first <<" - >" << (*(g.iter)).second <<endl;
         }

}
template<typename T>
void graph<T> :: show_map_element( graph<T>& g)
{

   cout<< (*g.vInfo[2].vtxMapLoc).first<<endl;
   cout<< (*g.vInfo[3].vtxMapLoc).second<<endl;
   cout<< (*g.vInfo[4].vtxMapLoc).first<<endl;
}


Output :    
          A -> 0    
          B -> 1   
          C -> 2   
          D -> 3    
          E -> 4
               ( nothing printed )
          0    
               ( nothing printed )
```

I am having doubt about output ( last 3 lines )
It should have been

```
C    
3     
E
```

because
`(*g.vInfo[2].vtxMapLoc)` points to ( C , 2 ) and it's first is C
`(*g.vInfo[3].vtxMapLoc)` points to ( D , 3 ) and it's second is 3
`(*g.vInfo[4].vtxMapLoc)` points to ( E , 4 ) and it's first is E

It seems that vector `vInfo` is not properly pointing to map `vtxMap`
`(*g.vInfo[index].vtxMapLoc) = vtxMap.find(index)`   is this pointing correct ??

Comment: `(*g.vInfo[index].vtxMapLoc) = vtxMap.find(index);` shouldn't even compile; you probably mean `g.vInfo[index].vtxMapLoc = vtxMap.find(index);`. In any way, `g.vInfo[index]` accesses an index out of bounds: the first time you get there, you've pushed an element at index 0, but are accessing an element at index 1. Finally, `vtxMap.find(index)` would most likely return `vtxMap.end()`, since `index` was never added as a key to the map. With all due respect, your code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik  : I have changed it the way you mentioned. But output is same (  I had not pasted the code from IDE but had pasted output ) Anyway but now it is updated.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik     I know it is not good code but I want graph representation using Map ( but not vector and list ).  Can you share better way to write graph using Map and sets ?? I am trying for this since 10 days but not able to write it.